# Referencing variables from anonymous classes in Java

Tags: java, anonymous-class

I am writing a setonclick listner, and I want to be able to refer to that button so that I can  change its properties.  I.e. make it disabled?

I get thismessage:

Cannot refer to a non-final variable confirmButton inside an inner class defined in a different method

```
        confirmButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            confirmButton.setEnabled(false);    
        }



    });
```

Comment: mmm... and where's code?

Answer (score 3):

This because you are probably trying to access that button from an anonymous class that you use in this way:

```
button.addActionListener(
  new MyListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      //do your things on button }
    }
  }
);
```

This doesn't work because in Java anonymous classes cannot see variables declared in methods in which they are declared too since their scope are separated. The only way to let your class see it is forcing the `final` constraint which assures the compiler that the variable won't change after being initialized, allowing it to extend its scope to the anonymous classes.

To quickly fix this you can access the button from the `ActionEvent` inside the `actionPerformed`:

```
((JButton)e.getSource()).setEnabled(false)
```

Otherwise you have to concretely declare your `ActionListener` somewhere or declare the buttons outside the method with `static` or `final` attribute.. especially if you plan to modify some elements by an action that is fired by another element.

Comment: +1 Just wanted to add ... Or your class can implement ActionListener and then access it as a local variable from inside actionPerformed.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend against the `getSource`; the documentation doesn't promise that it will be your button.  You can either make your button `final` in the scope, or use a more sophisticated class

```
public class ComponentRelevantOnClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {

  private JComponent component;

  public ComponentRelevantOnClickListener(JComponent component) {
    this.component = component;
  }
}

// then, in your code...

confirmButton.setOnClickListener(new ComponentRelevantOnClickListener(confirmButton) {

    public void onClick(View view) {
        component.setEnabled(false);    
    }
});
```

If you move toward a design of action and listener classes instead of anonymous subclasses, you get more chance for re-use (you can already see that `ComponentRelevantOnClickListener` could be replaced with a "DisableOnClickListneer" that you can use anywhere for this purpose), and your code will be overall better designed.

Answer (score 0):

vars that are referenced within anonymous classes need to be defined as `final` in Java. Jon Skeet has a great example of this nestled within [this article](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter5/Closures.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Anonymous inner classes can only access variables from the outer scope if they are `final`. Assuming you only assign to the `confirmButton` once, I suggest simply tagging it as `final`.

```
final JButton confirmButton = new JButton();
```